# What would be the best mapping between html inputs and java types inside a class

Tags: java, html, spring

I am not an expert in html + java. I was trying to design a user form to collect data and then to bind it to a Java class using spring. I am using html inputs like

- text
- radio button
- checkbox
- select
- date
- buttons
- tel
- file
- image

Now, for text input, the corresponding Java type will be String. What would be the best Types or collections for other html inputs or vice-versa.

Comment: Depends on implementation. For `checkbox`es `Boolean` may be used, if `indeterminate` is not used, for `radio` buttons and `select`s some enumerated list can be used, for most others `String` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on what you will be doing with the data. As you said for text input you are using string. For radio boxes you can use Boolean. For check box you can choose a string or an enum.

Comment: RadioBoxes: what if the number of choices are more then two, and could spring automatically bind the values posted - to the backing bean.
For others, same?

Comment: yes... If you create a DTO at the backend with setters and getters you can use @RequestMapping in the controller and Spring will take care of mapping